Meaning of バチバチのガチだ
I am not certain about the meaning of バチバチのガチ, especially ガチ. Also, I wonder if this の is the same の discussed in this question.


Without any context given, it seems that the character thinks 水原 put an earnest effort to look her formal. Here, バチバチ is used to emphasize the seriousness he sensed, and ガチ means 本気. And, yes, this use of の is the same の you mentioned.

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe バチバチ in this panel is used in sense of something like 完璧なおしゃれの様子 when talking about fashion, according to this article. I think it is closely related to キメキメ.
As for ガチ, it probably means something like "hardcore" and it is similar to the one used in ガチ勢. Saying that a dress is ガチ indicates that its wearer puts way beyond average effort to look good.
